# Server Socket no Windows Azure, como capturar Ip Externo?

Tags: c#, socket, microsoft-azure

Desenvolvi uma Console App, que cria um Server Socket assíncrono. 
Pode ser visto um parecido [AQUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx).

Tenho também uma Web App comum, que consome as informações inseridas no banco de dados pelo Console App.

Surgiu a necessidade de subir essas aplicações para o Windows Azure. 
Dei uma vasculhada na web e encontrei a possibilidade de associar minha Console App a minha Web App. Dessa maneira, criando um WebJobs associado ao meu projeto web, a Console App seria iniciada automaticamente com o projeto web e sem a necessidade de eu reescreve-la. Essa solução está [AQUI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#convertlink)

Pois bem, funcionou em partes. A Console App executou corretamente e está em execução, mas o IP que a aplicação utiliza para escuta (IPEndPoint) é o 127.0.0.1.

Isso era esperado pois estava usando o mesmo código do exemplo para testes:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Porta);
```

Consequentemente, ao tentar enviar informações para o Server Socket, ele não existe!!

As grande questão é: 
- Como capturar o IP Externo que o Azure está utilizando, via linha de código, para poder criar o EndPoint e associá-lo ao Socket?